# Change -- to . for all files in a directory

Tags: bash, rename

I need to rename all the files in a directory. Some examples of the source filenames are:

```
alpha--sometext.381928
comp--moretext.7294058
```

The resultant files would be renamed as:

```
alpha.sometext.381928
comp.moretext.7294058
```

The number of characters before and after the -- is *not* consistant.

The script needs to work on current installations of Ubuntu and FreeBSD. These are lean LAMP servers so only the necessary packages have been installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Via bash:

```
for file in *--*; do
    mv "${file}" "${file/--/.}"
done
```

The magic is in `${file/--/.}` which is the value of `${file}` except with each "--" changed to a "."

Comment: Nice one. I was trying to write one but you beat me to it!

Comment: You should always quote any variable that contains filenames. `mv "${file}" "${file/--/.}"`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - I've updated my answer, but to be precise, you need to quote anything that may have whitespace in them.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to pure shell, you can use `rename`, a standard utility that comes with Perl. It's more convenient for simple cases.

```
rename 's/--/./' *
```